# apache_request_headers function for NGINX

Tags: php, apache, nginx, http-headers

> will **`apache_request_headers`** function work on **NGINX** Web
>   Server. If not what is function for **NGINX** parallel to it

Answer (score 3):

Some people have written their own functions on the PHP docs site.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('apache_request_headers') ) {

function apache_request_headers() {
  $arh = array();
  $rx_http = '/\AHTTP_/';
  foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) {
    if( preg_match($rx_http, $key) ) {
      $arh_key = preg_replace($rx_http, '', $key);
      $rx_matches = array();
      // do some nasty string manipulations to restore the original letter case
      // this should work in most cases
      $rx_matches = explode('_', $arh_key);
      if( count($rx_matches) > 0 and strlen($arh_key) > 2 ) {
        foreach($rx_matches as $ak_key => $ak_val) $rx_matches[$ak_key] = ucfirst($ak_val);
        $arh_key = implode('-', $rx_matches);
      }
      $arh[$arh_key] = $val;
    }
  }
  return( $arh );
  }
}
```

See if that helps (haven't tried it).

Comment: good effort. but can't we avoid these `foreach` loops. i want more optimum solution

Comment: if it works, use it, and stop worrying about micro-optimisations ;-) or, head to the link and you will see other examples that people have written

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

> Fetches all HTTP request headers from the current request. Works in the Apache, FastCGI, CLI, FPM and NSAPI server module in Netscape/iPlanet/SunONE webservers.

If you're running PHP via an FPM socket on UNIX, or using the FastCGI interface, this function will work. The fact is begins with `apache` is misleading, but is hardly atypical of PHP function naming.